# Coloringnumber of graph with clique cutset

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph with clique cutset $K$.
This means $K$ is a clique and $G-K$ falls into multiple components $H_i$.

I'm trying to prove that the coloring number is equal to the largest coloringnumber of the induced subgraph of the union of a resulting component $H_i$ and $K$.

So:

$ \chi(G) = max\{\chi(G[V(H_i)\cup K])\}$

So I'm trying the following argument:

Let us suppose, that for $i=1$ we get the maximal coloringnumber q.
We know that there no edges between any $H_i$. Otherwise K would'nt be a clique cutset.
Since $K$ is a clique, we can choose a fixed coloring for the vertices of $K$ with $|K|$ different colors.

For every other $H_i$ with $i\neq1$ we can now just chose the $q'$-coloring with $q' \leq q$ by chsoing the colors as we would've with the the induced subgraph of $K\cup H_i$, since the coloring of $K$ is fixed. This way we have found valid a $q$-coloring for $G$.
Therefore the claim is proven.

Can somebody tell me if I'm right?

Comment: I think it looks right. Assuming $S$ is supposed to be $K$?

Comment: Oh, youre right. I fixed the typo.